# Is it considered as work to prepare his salary negotiation?

Tags: salary, negotiation, work-time

I am going to have my next salary negotiation in the next week. As I want to be ready and have good arguments, I started to prepare sales analysis, and other data I find relevant for my negotiation.

However, this takes some time to prepare this kind of analysis and I am not sure how this analysis can be used out of this context.

So my question is: As preparing this is not really bringing anything to the company, Is it considered as work to prepare this kind of documents for my negotiation with my managers? Am I supposed to do that on my working time (at work) or later (overtime or even at home)?

Also to note:  I might have trouble it doing from home, as the analysis tools and data are only on our server.

Comment: Doing work to negotiate your salary does not seem like it would be in your job description.  If you cannot work from home then you should stay late to work on it “off the clock”

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot of work, but it's work for your own benefit, not your company's (similar to interviewing at another company, or even mowing your lawn). As such you should do it on your own time.

Some workplaces will be OK with you doing personal tasks on company time, as long as it doesn't impact what you deliver. You'll need to judge whether this is appropriate where you're employed.

Comment: This is for an internal process of course it should be on company time as is prepping for a 121 with your manager>

Comment: @Neuromancer why would you need to spend more than a few minutes preparing for a one-to-one with your manager? It may vary in different professions or parts of the world, but for me a one-to-one means talking about how things are going in your day to day work. You prepare for that by working day to day. Which is obviously of benefit to the company.

Comment: you would be going through your years achievements and goals and setting ones for the future - basicly making sure you don't get a bad appraisal even more so in a professional job where CPD is a requirement

Comment: @Neuromancer a one-to-one is not synonymous with a performance appraisal to me. I guess that's part of our difference of opinion.

Comment: Difference of opinion sounds like something HR would say

Comment: I used to have to write in-depth self evaluations every 6 months for my review (which was essentially a salary negotiation since my aim was to prove how much I'd improved since my last review). I probably spent around 6 hours prepping over the 2 weeks leading up to me handing it in and this time was in the companies hours (there was a specific task when filling out time sheets). Provided you're still hitting any deadlines in the lead up, I would agree that it is prep for a company meeting and therefore on company time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

You are preparing for an internal meeting - internal meetings are part of your Job.

You would prepare for a 121 meeting with your manager on company time or an internal project meeting. This meeting is part of that whole process of your personal development.